# base58 cannot get 34 chars results (as Bitcoin address does) but 68 chars

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, public-key, address-generation, base58

I am trying to convert public key hex to Bitcoin address.

From this website http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address, I can do some test.

For example, I have this public key:

```
04b4d653fcbb4b96000c99343f23b08a44fa306031e0587f9e657ab4a2541129368d7d9bb05cd8afbdf7705a6540d98028236965553f91bf1c5b4f70073f55b55d
```

According to the website, the address should be:

```
1DU8Hi1sbHTpEP9vViBEkEw6noeUrgKkJH
```

which is the base58 encode of `0088C2D2FA846282C870A76CADECBE45C4ACD72BB655DA1216`.

However, if I do Base58 encoding directly on `0088C2D2FA846282C870A76CADECBE45C4ACD72BB655DA1216` on this website https://www.browserling.com/tools/base58-encode, I will get:

```
bSLwwticQjhNvEtqTMZXbn3dLmFrPvNrDGE4hmHsfADpHWb3b2ruh3XqtNzv8ESS8V6V
```

which is totally different from the 34-char Bitcoin address.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4):

When you use that site, you are encoding the hex as a hex string, not of the actual bytes that they should be. The base58 encoding for addresses operates on the bytes themselves which are represented in the hex string. However that website is just encoding the hex string (which, as bytes, is double the length and is entirely other data).

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Chow told you *why*. Now I'll tell you how.

First, convert hex to ASCII (I suggest [this website](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html))

(I can't copy the ASCII result below, since that would cause problems.)

Then copy the weird-looking ASCII text it created, and paste it to the Base58 Encoder.

[image]

Done!